# asp.net mvc - create dropdownlist from foreignkey database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> > hi
>
> I have the following Models and Controllers listed below
>
> > i try to bring in the dropdownlist in view creation by foreignkey
> >     "title" but i can not get error in create / save
> >
> > please help with code - (I'm a beginner)

```
     imprumutsController.cs
        ....
           // GET: imprumuts/Create
                public ActionResult Create()
                {

                    ViewBag.idcarti_stoc = new SelectList(db.carti_stoc, "idcarti", "idcarti" );
                    ViewBag.idcititor = new SelectList(db.citiors, "Idcititor", "Numele");
                    // ViewBag.idcititor = new SelectList(db.cartis, "Idcarti", "Titlu");
                     ViewBag.idcarti = new SelectList(db.cartis, "Idcarti", "Titlu");

                    return View();
                }

            // POST: imprumuts/Create
            [enter image description here][1]
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Idimprumut,idcarti_stoc,idcititor,data_imprumut,durata,data_restituire")] imprumut imprumut)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.imprumuts.Add(imprumut);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                ViewBag.idcarti_stoc = new SelectList(db.carti_stoc, "idcarti_stoc", "idcarti_stoc", imprumut.carti_stoc.carti.Titlu);
                // ViewBag.idcart_stoc = new SelectList(db.carti_stoc, "idcarti_stoc", "idcarti_stoc", imprumut.idcarti_stoc);
                // ViewBag.idcititor = new SelectList(db.citiors, "Idcititor", "idcititor", imprumut.idcititor);
                return View(imprumut);
            }



     imprumuts - Create.cshtml
         ...
        @*  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idcarti_stoc, "idcarti_stoc", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            *@
                 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idcarti_stoc, "Titlu", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("idcarti", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idcarti_stoc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

   namespace carti_v2.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

        public partial class imprumut
        {
            public int Idimprumut { get; set; }
            public int idcarti_stoc { get; set; }
            public int idcititor { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public System.DateTime data_imprumut { get; set; }

            public int durata { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> data_restituire { get; set; }

            public virtual carti_stoc carti_stoc { get; set; }
            public virtual citior citior { get; set; }
        }
    }


        namespace carti_v2.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class carti_stoc
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            public carti_stoc()
            {
                this.imprumuts = new HashSet<imprumut>();
            }

            public int idcarti_stoc { get; set; }
            public int idcarti { get; set; }
            public bool disponibil { get; set; }

            public virtual carti carti { get; set; }
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<imprumut> imprumuts { get; set; }
        }
    }

*****

    namespace carti_v2.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class carti
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            public carti()
            {
                this.carti_stoc = new HashSet<carti_stoc>();
            }

            public int idcarti { get; set; }
            public string Autor { get; set; }
            public string Titlu { get; set; }
            public string Domeniu { get; set; }
            public string ISBN { get; set; }

            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<carti_stoc> carti_stoc { get; set; }
```

Comment: the error: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_imprumut_carti_stoc". The conflict occurred in database "carti", table "dbo.carti_stoc", column 'idcarti_stoc'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: In my answer code, where I say THIS Needs to be unique, you should use the identity in the table and use that as the primary key.

Comment: If you use identity autonumber, you can use a single SaveChanges()

Comment: You can even use cascading adds with identity.  Start with what I have presented you please

Answer (score 0):

Please remember, if you have a foreign key on a field, then that field needs to have a matching value in the primary field.

You need to put separate SaveChanges() so relationships agree.  Like FK_imprumut_carti_stoc failing means some carti_stoc imprumut fields do not appear in imprumut

You can do this:

```
   public ActionResult Index63()
    {
        //use your dbcontext
        using (BreazEntities19 entity = new BreazEntities19())
        {
            //entity.SaveChanges();
            imprumut i = new imprumut
            {
                carti_stoc = 1,  //THIS Needs to be unique
                data_imprumut = DateTime.Parse("12/12/12"),
                data_restituire = DateTime.Parse("12/12/12"),
                durata = 1,
                idcarti_stoc = 1,
                idcititor = 1
            };
            entity.imprumuts.Add(i);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            carti_stoc cs = new carti_stoc
            {
                carti = 1, //THIS Needs to be unique
                disponibil = true,
                idcarti = 1,
                impromut = i.carti_stoc
            };
            entity.carti_stoc.Add(cs);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            carti c = new carti { Autor = "ap1", carti_stoc = cs.carti, Domeniu = "ap", ISBN = "ap", Titlu = "ap" };
            entity.cartis.Add(c);
            entity.SaveChanges();
        }
```

You can wrap everything in a transaction:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                 {
                    //Put your work in here with multiple save changes
                    using (myDbcontext context = new myDbcontext()){
                        ...
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    scope.Complete();
                }
```

Comment: Thnaks! @kblau.  
I just want to load the name of the "Titlu" of from the db.carti table in the DropDownList. As I posted the code, I get the "Titlu" from the Viewbag, but  - in saving - has idcarti (from the viewbag -link) and not idcarte_stoc - and it gives me the error.
The connection comes from the db.imprumut value -> db.carti_stoc -> db.carti ("Title" field) - That's what I can not do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your view model, use your namespace:

```
namespace Testy20161006.Models
{
    public partial class carti
    {
        public string selectedItem {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Here is your controller:

```
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index63(carti model)
    {
        //put a breakpoint here to see selected idcarte_stoc, as you want
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index63()
    {
        //use your dbcontext name, be aware that you are not explicitely disposing of the obj
        BreazEntities19 entity = new BreazEntities19();
        SelectList selectList = new SelectList(entity.cartis, "carti_stoc", "Titlu");
        ViewBag.idcarti = selectList;

        return View();
    }
```

Here is your view:

```
@model Testy20161006.Models.carti

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index63</title>

</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedItem,
                    new SelectList(ViewBag.idcarti, "Value", "Text"),
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
        <input type="submit" value="click" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @danb can you please let me know if you looked at my answer, and what else you need specifically

Comment: hi @kblau if code is  '@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedItem' the error is "'imprumut' does not contain a definition for 'selectedItem' and no extension method 'selectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'imprumut' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) carti_v2

Comment: and if I change to '@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.carti_stoc.carti.selectedItem, new SelectList(ViewBag.idcarti, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })'  I have value in dropdownlist and when save the error is _ The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_imprumut_carti_stoc". The conflict occurred in database "carti", table "dbo.carti_stoc", column 'idcarti_stoc'._

Comment: your suggested  model  insert into : 'namespace carti_v2.Models
{ using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public partial class carti
    {public carti()
        {  this.carti_stoc = new HashSet<carti_stoc>();}
        public int idcarti { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        public string Titlu { get; set; }
        public string Domeniu { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<carti_stoc> carti_stoc { get; set; }
       ** public string selectedItem { get; set; }**  }'

Comment: @danb I apologize.  Can we please start over and I can help you when I get to work tomorrow.  I had to derive the table structure and referential integrity based on your post.  Perhaps, we can start there, if you can script out your tables and referential integrity (PK--<FK) for and post it here, I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

here is image with database structure -diagram
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Txx.png)

Eventually I think it should dropdown in the cascade with the link between idcarti and iscarti_stoc.
But I do not know how to retrieve from view the idcards selected to make the controller the second selection ...